# Problems with the new mobile interface

Tags: bug, design

Stackexhange just updated the mobile views. At first everything broke, but today the up and down vote started working. The main problem now is that if a post has wide images they dont scale to fit the page. While im ok with that it has 2 problems:

1. there is no way i can scroll sideways as the width clips off.
2. wide images make the text wider and that text now also clips with wide images present. Again no way to be seen.

Comment: The design team monitors posts tagged `design` and `bug`, so they should be along shortly. Could you post screenshots of the problems you're talking about?

Comment: Under which browser, platform...?

Comment: android nexus 5, sailfish jolla. Since these are completely different platforms id say its a global problem @Sklivvz

Comment: @joojaa which browser? Firefox has a known bug around max-width

Comment: well the sailfish browser (im currenrly using) is based on gecko yes, but its not a firefox, same enginebase tough. But im pretty sure the browser in the nexus was chrome or webkit based. @Slivvz, still does not matter engineering does not get to deflect blame, you handle it or its failure regardless of source. It night not be your faults but clients dont and should not need to care. In either case the old system worked right this one does not, which says to me bug or no bug it can be done.